# Is S3 to Apache Storm spout available?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-storm

I need to read the new files arriving at S3 with Apache Storm spout. Does Apache Storm have a spout to read data from S3 directly? I have tried to find a spout to ingest data directly from S3 and looked into how to use Amazon Kinesis for the workaround, but I need a direct approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's such a thing. I'd have a look at AWS's S3 integration with SNS/SQS. Creating a spout to read from SQS should be trivial.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html